# .gitconfig: file does not exist in Docker

Tags: git, docker, git-config

I'm trying to set the git defaults in my Dockerfile (Ubuntu 18.04).

The user name is `xavier`, this is what I have in the Dockerfile:

```
Run apt update && apt -y full-upgrade && apt install -y git
...
...
Copy --chown=xavier:xavier .gitconfig /home/xavier
Copy .gitconfig /root
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Step 20/30 : Copy --chown=xavier:xavier .gitconfig /home/xavier
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat .gitconfig: file does not exist
```

What process creates the .gitconfig file (I assume it would be created when git is installed)? How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

```
root@xavier-desktop:/# ls -la
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar  1 22:26 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar  1 22:26 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Mar  1 22:26 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec  5  2020 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  780 Mar  1 22:26 dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  5  2020 dst
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar  1 22:26 etc
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar  1 21:32 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar  1 21:27 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Mar  1 21:29 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 314 root root    0 Mar  1 22:26 proc
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Mar  1 21:32 root
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  195 Feb 15 20:03 ros_entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec  5  2020 run
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Dec  5  2020 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  12 root root    0 Mar  1 20:01 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Mar  1 22:26 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Nov 19  2020 var
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Feb 28 22:03 workspace
root@xavier-desktop:/# cd /home/        
root@xavier-desktop:/home# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Mar  1 21:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Mar  1 22:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 xavier xavier 4096 Mar  1 21:32 xavier
root@xavier-desktop:/home# cd xavier/
root@xavier-desktop:/home/xavier# ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 xavier xavier 4096 Mar  1 21:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   4096 Mar  1 21:32 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 xavier xavier  220 Apr  4  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 xavier xavier 3771 Apr  4  2018 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 xavier xavier  807 Apr  4  2018 .profile
```

Comment: It's telling you that there is no file named `.gitconfig` in your current directory. That seems like it's probably true, your `.gitconfig` file typically lives in your home directory. You won't be able to copy that in a Dockerfile (because you can only access files in your "build context" -- usually, the directory in which you are running `docker build`).

Comment: @larsks I added my filesystem (after `docker build`) but I still don't see `.gitconfig`

Comment: Why are you trying to copy a file that doesn't exist? Why do you need a gitconfig? Maybe you don't even need those lines in your Dockerfile, but we can only answer adequately if you give more information on what you're trying to do

Comment: @LeonardoDagnino maybe that should be a separate post.

Comment: Installing Git *does not* create a `.gitconfig` file. That would be senseless: the point of a (personal) `.gitconfig` file is to conform to your (human) preferences, which vary from human to human. Without a `.gitconfig` Git uses the compiled defaults, whatever those are, and those *may* be sufficient, and if they're not the human (you) is supposed to create the human's preferences file.